# Blogger template alignment issue at the bottom of the blog

Tags: jquery, html, css, blogger

After doing the Advanced blogger settings like changing color to the `lower-wrapper` div changes are not effected and also page alignments are changed. I went through the `F12` key to find the issue with bottom alignment to my blog. But not able to find. Here is my blog url: http://javabynataraj.blogspot.com and the template of the blog you can [download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9F97lUX9bz3QzRhbVUyNHB6OUk/edit?usp=sharing). The [Original Template](https://app.box.com/shared/7rsg30doj0) i am using from [Our Blogger Templates](http://www.ourblogtemplates.com/2009/10/blogger-templates-webnolia.html).

```
<div id="lower-wrapper">
```

in this div my blog content got changed. please find the image below attached. In my blog this div is not displaying as shown below..

[image]

Comment: Is it just me or does the screenshot not bear any resemblance to the site linked to?

Comment: no point posting download links.....nobody will download your files

Comment: @3rror404 previously my blog having the design given in the image. But it got crashed because of some changes. Now i am not able to reset the code..